# How to create a camera capture guide line bars

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I would like to mimic the Windows Phone default camera application where two white bars [ ] show up while the camera is about to take a picture. I have been researching but I do not know how to implement such a feature in my own application. I have set up all the camera buttons and and everything works correctly, but this is a feature I would certainly like to have. I was going to just display the bars and hide them over the camera viewfinder, and then show them as visible using a DispatcherTimer to control the timing. The only problem is, I'm not sure how to do this and then make the DispatcherTimer Tick event only activate right before the camera takes a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to show the focus bars is to use a textblock with opened and closed brackets "[  ]" which you show and hide as you focus on some point. When the user taps on a point, you simply do:

```
Point tapLocation = e.GetPosition(viewfinderCanvas);

// Position the focus brackets with the estimated offsets.
focusBrackets.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, tapLocation.X - 30);
focusBrackets.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, tapLocation.Y - 28);

// Determine the focus point.
double focusXPercentage = tapLocation.X / viewfinderCanvas.Width;
double focusYPercentage = tapLocation.Y / viewfinderCanvas.Height;

// Show the focus brackets and focus at point.
focusBrackets.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
cam.FocusAtPoint(focusXPercentage, focusYPercentage);
```

Code taken from MSDN, where you can find the whole implementation:

[How to: Use Camera Focus in an Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202964%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)